# Sylius: How to inject data variable of it's own record in a grid rendering

Tags: symfony, grid, symfony4, inject, sylius

I want to add something to the displaying of the channel of an order grid in admin view depending on some of the products within that order. I would need a way to inject the data of the record into the twig template in example.

Can't figure it out. The grid looks like this:

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        sylius_admin_order:
            driver:
                name: doctrine/orm
                options:
                    class: "%sylius.model.order.class%"
                    repository:
                        method: createListQueryBuilder
            sorting:
                number: desc
            fields:
                ...
                channel:
                    type: twig
                    label: sylius.ui.channel
                    sortable: channel.code
                    options:
                        template: "@SyliusAdmin/Order/Grid/Field/channel.html.twig"
```

I see that in other columns they add vars: under options: in example like this:

```
                    options:
                        template: ...
                        vars: 
                            labels: "@SyliusAdmin/Order/Label/State"
```

but how to do it with itself, I mean with the rest of the data from the record? 
I would need something like this:

```
                    options:
                        template: "@SyliusAdmin/Order/Grid/Field/channel.html.twig"
                        vars: 
                            order: self
```

Does anyone know a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you should to create a new template and set its path into Grid field options -> template. Then get your variable with `{{ options.vars.order }}` in that template.

How it works:

Sylius-Grid passes a `options` variable into template at rendering. For example, how looks standard `label` parameter:

Grid definition in @SyliusAdmin/config/grids/order.yml:

```
...
                paymentState:
                    type: twig
                    label: sylius.ui.payment_state
                    sortable: ~
                    options:
                        template: "@SyliusUi/Grid/Field/state.html.twig"
                        vars:
                            labels: 
...
```

@SyliusUi/Grid/Field/label.html.twig:

```
{% set value = 'sylius.ui.' ~ data %}

{% if options.vars.labels is defined %}
    {% include [(options.vars.labels ~ '/' ~ data ~ '.html.twig'), '@SyliusUi/Label/_default.html.twig'] with {'value': value} %}
{% else %}
    {% include '@SyliusUi/Label/_default.html.twig' with {'value': value} %}
{% endif %}
```

In this example, passed variable `labels`, which are passed in Grid Yaml definition, available in Twig `options.vars.labels` variable.

**EDIT**: if you want to access entity object other attributes in template, not only `channels` as in this example, add this to your grid field definition root:

```
                channel:
                    type: twig
                    label: sylius.ui.channel
                    path: .
```

you might need to refresh Twig cache with `php bin/console cache:clear`. Read more about it in https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.6/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusGridBundle/field_types.html#twig-twig

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But that's the problem: How do I make it so that options.vars.order WILL be filled with the correct value? Do I need to extend the ResourceController and manually set in the order variable in code? Or can I do it in grid definintion? 

EDIT: Sorry for initial cut off comment

Comment: I don't see need to define it in grid definition, can you just use `{{ data }}` in template? In your case data will contain Order object

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately {{ data }} only contains the name of the channel, not the order record which the channel is assigned to. EDIT: It's the template "@SyliusAdmin/Order/Grid/Field/channel.html.twig" the grid definition is in: AdminBundle/Resources/config/grids/order.yml

Comment: sorry, in this situation put a `path: .` below `type: twig` line.It will make your `{{ data }}` have entire object instead of object field value

Comment: Unfortunately adding a path: . does not change anything. {{ data }} still contains only the channel name. It now looks like this:                  

   channel:
                    type: twig
                    label: sylius.ui.channel
                    path: .
                    sortable: channel.code
                    options:
                        template: "@SyliusAdmin/Order/Grid/Field/channel.html.twig"

Comment: yes, you should also create your own template in /templates dir and put its path like this `template: "custom.html.twig"` instead of `SyliusAdmin/Order/Grid/Field/channel.html.twig`. After that write your own logic in your template, for example, `{{ dump(data) }}`. About `path: .` see https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.6/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusGridBundle/field_types.html#twig-twig

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts! I have an appointment now, will try within 2 hours.

Comment: It was a caching issue, it works with path: . It was the solution. Thanks a lot! Should I mark this answer as the solution or do you want to formulate a new answer about it?

Comment: I think yes, it describes an question that you asked

Comment: ok, ah you can also edit your answer just to include path: . as this was the important missing piece of information.

Comment: I just opened another thread which is quite close to the subject. I am in fact pretty sure you can also answer this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59648295/sylius-how-to-reference-your-own-twig-template-in-a-grid